# Derive another address with the same pubkey and different uuid

Tags: rust, anchor, solana, solana-web3js

I want to program a smart contract that stores data of a random generated "planet". I generated the data for the planet in another program and i use a uuid to recreate the planet.
Now i want to use this uuid and a public key to create the address. I tried to use PDA's for that and it kind of works. The first address i derive with the pubkey and the uuid works just fine, but if i want to derive another address with the same pubkey and different uuid I get a CPI Error.

Had anybody common experiences or is the way i use PDA's wrong and if so how would you store the data?

My code:

```
pub fn create_planet(ctx: Context<CreatePlanet>, owner: Pubkey, authority: Pubkey, bump: u8, uuid: u64) -> Result<()>{
//pub fn create_planet(ctx: Context<CreatePlanet>, owner: Pubkey, authority: Pubkey, bump: u8) -> Result<()>{
    msg!("test");
    let planet: &mut Account<Planet> = &mut ctx.accounts.planet;
    let payer: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.payer;
    /*if data.chars().count() > 212 {
        return Err(ErrorCode::dataTooLong.into());
    }*/
    if planet.owner == anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey::default() {
        planet.owner = owner;
    }
    planet.authority = authority;
    planet.bump = bump;
    planet.uuid = uuid;
    Ok(())
}
```

Struct:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump: u8, uuid: u64)]
//#[instruction(bump: u8)]
pub struct CreatePlanet<'info>{
   #[account(init, seeds = [b"planet".as_ref(), 
   payer.key.as_ref(), uuid.to_le_bytes().as_ref()], bump, 
   payer=payer, space=Planet::LEN)]
   //#[account(init, seeds = [payer.key.as_ref(), 
   uuid.to_le_bytes().as_ref()], bump, payer=payer, 
   space=Planet::LEN)]
   pub planet: Account<'info, Planet>,
   #[account(mut)]
   pub payer: Signer<'info>,
   pub system_program: Program <'info, System>
}
```

RPC Call:

```
const uuid = new anchor.BN(parseInt((Date.now() / 1000).toString()));
const uuidBuffer = uuid.toBuffer('le', 8);

const [sandboxPda, sandboxBump] = 
await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([Buffer.from('planet'), wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(), uuidBuffer], program.programId);
//await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(), uuid], program.programId);


console.log("PDA: ", sandboxPda.toBase58());
console.log("Bump: ", sandboxBump);

await program.rpc.createPlanet(wallet.publicKey, ourWallet.publicKey, sandboxBump, uuid, {
  accounts: {
    planet: sandboxPda, //planet.publicKey
    payer: wallet.publicKey,
    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId
  },
  signers: [wallet]
});
```

It causes to the following error:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4068:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4030:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:284:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:144:14)
      at Object.rpc [as createPlanet] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you upload the code where you call the CPI?

Comment: Above is everything i am calling unfortunately.